UISwipeGestureRecognizer Not Triggering Consistently on a Custom UIView with Blur Effect
I'm building a custom notification system for my iOS app where temporary notification views are displayed on top of the screen. These views have a layered structure with a UIVisualEffectView for a blur effect and a content view containing icons and text.
I want users to dismiss the notification by swiping down. I have successfully found that the swipe gestures are being added to the views, but somehow, the swipes are not being detected, not even taps or pan gestures.
The swipe gesture sometimes fails to trigger consistently. Below is the relevant code:
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        // Show a notification after 1 second
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.showNotification(message: "Swipe down to dismiss!")
        }
    }
    
    func showNotification(message: String) {
        let notificationView = createNotificationView(message: message)
        view.addSubview(notificationView)
        positionNotification(notificationView, above: nil)
        
        // Automatically dismiss after 3 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            self.dismissNotification(notificationView)
        }
    }
    
    private func createNotificationView(message: String) -> UIView {
        // Create the notification view
        let notificationView = UIView()
        notificationView.backgroundColor = .clear
        notificationView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        notificationView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        notificationView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        notificationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        notificationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        // Add blur effect
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = notificationView.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        blurEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        notificationView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        
        // Add content to the blur effect view
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = message
        label.textColor = .label
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurEffectView.contentView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurEffectView.contentView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        // Add swipe gesture recognizer
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(_:)))
        swipeGesture.direction = .down
        swipeGesture.delegate = self
        notificationView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)  
      
        return notificationView
    }
    
    private func positionNotification(_ notificationView: UIView, above previousNotificationView: UIView?) {
        notificationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let previousView = previousNotificationView {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                notificationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousView.topAnchor, constant: -10),
                notificationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                notificationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
                notificationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
            ])
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                notificationView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 60),
                notificationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                notificationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
                notificationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
            ])
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func handleSwipe(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let notificationView = gesture.view else { return }
        print("Swipe detected on notification!")
        dismissNotification(notificationView)
    }
    
    private func dismissNotification(_ notificationView: UIView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            notificationView.alpha = 0
        }) { _ in
            notificationView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

}


Same approach has been working for other views, but they were declared at the parent class level, while this "notification view" is something that is initialized within a function, but the values and everything else works well. This should have worked, so I am not sure what I am missing.
Would love some advice.

A gesture can only be added to one view, not three.

Thanks for the comment, just that I tried adding to one view only. But there is also another swipe gesture for another view in the same view controller.

@HangarRash Just FYI, I was able to resolve the issue by changing it to a view controller instead, it seems UIView has some restrictions. Thanks for the hint.

Worked around the issue by changing from UIView to UIViewController.

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController {
    private let message: String
    private let textColor: UIColor
    private let backgroundColor: UIColor
    private let iconName: String?
    private let iconColor: UIColor
    private let iconHeight: CGFloat
    private let displayDuration: Double
    
    init(message: String, textColor: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor, iconName: String?, iconColor: UIColor, iconHeight: CGFloat, displayDuration: Double) {
        self.message = message
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.iconName = iconName
        self.iconColor = iconColor
        self.iconHeight = iconHeight
        self.displayDuration = displayDuration
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        setupNotificationView()
    }
    
    private func setupNotificationView() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear  // Make sure background is transparent
        
        // Create the notification content view
        let notificationContentView = UIView()
        notificationContentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        notificationContentView.layer.cornerRadius = ViewSetUpManager.mediumCornerRadius
        notificationContentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        notificationContentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        notificationContentView.clipsToBounds = true
        notificationContentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        // Add blur effect
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        notificationContentView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        blurEffectView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        // Add icon and label
        let iconImageView = UIImageView()
        if let iconName = iconName {
            iconImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: iconName)
            iconImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            iconImageView.tintColor = iconColor
            iconImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(iconImageView)
            iconImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
                make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
                make.width.height.equalTo(iconHeight)
            }
        }
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = message
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: ViewSetUpManager.shared.genericTitleFontSize(), weight: .regular)
        label.textColor = textColor
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blurEffectView.contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.trailing).offset(8)
            make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        // Add notificationContentView to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(notificationContentView)
        notificationContentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.bottom.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide).offset(-(self.tabBarHeight() + 50))
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview().multipliedBy(0.9)
            make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(60)
        }
        
        // Add swipe gesture recognizer
        let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipeGesture(_:)))
        swipeGesture.direction = [.left, .down, .right]
        swipeGesture.delegate = self
        notificationContentView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
        
        // Automatically dismiss after displayDuration
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + displayDuration) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    private func tabBarHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return self.presentingViewController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
    }
    
    @objc private func handleSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension NotificationViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    // Implement delegate methods if necessary
}



